# array.map() does not work as expected to render <li> component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render multiple `<li>` components using map() function.
Nothing is rendered on the screen. I don't get any error message either, so I have no clue.

```
        reviewCard = reviews.map((review, index) => {
            const url = `http://localhost:3001/users/${review.user_id}`;
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <ReviewCard 
                                review={review} 
                                user={response.data}
                            />
                        </li>
                    );
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        );
```

The following code works though.

```
        reviewCard = reviews.map((review, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
                <ReviewCard review={review} />
            </li>
        ));
```

I would appreciate it if you have any suggestion.

Thanks :)

Comment: `.get()` is async, so your map converts each element into nothing (the return value of your anonymous function).  You want to collect the promises returned by axios and then use those to do your render.  (Remember to include some way to preserve order)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I am a beginner and not sure how to treat those promises yet. Is it possible for you to make it more specific and give some simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 1st use promise all to resolve all async code and then map the to create your ReviewCard

```
let promiseList = reviews.map((review, index) => {
  const url = `http://localhost:3001/users/${review.user_id}`;
  return axios.get(url);
});

let reviewCard;
Promise.all(promiseList).then((responses) => {
  reviewCard = responses.map((response,index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <ReviewCard review={review[index]} user={response.data} />
      </li>
    );
  });
});
```

Explanation:

1. Firstly we are creating an array of promises i.e. your get requests.
2. Now we resolve all the promises requests using promise.all so that we can finally get an array of responses.
3. Now we have all sync code so we easily can map the responses array to our ReviewCard.

Comment: `review` will be always undefined inside `<ReviewCard review={review}` as that is only defined inside `reviews.map((review, index)`

Comment: @palaѕн thanks updated my answer. I missed seeing `review={review} `

Comment: Thanks! That totally makes sense now.

Comment: @ryo.m.code, since you are new, let me tell you that you have to click on the checkmark to mark an answer as an accepted answer and you can alps click on up arrow to upvote an answer.

Comment: I did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not the best place to call some async functions. Axios then doesn't call rerender of your component. You have to use useEffect to call axios method and useState for rerender you component and store the results.

Just see the next code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const Cards = ({ reviews }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]); // use state rerender component on each call setUsers;

  const fetchUsers = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      // collect user requests to array
      const listOfRequests = reviews.map((item) => axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users/${item.user_id}`));
      const responses = await Promise.all(listOfRequests);
      const users = responses.map((item) => item.data);
      setUsers(users);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  if (users.length === 0) {
    return <div>something happens</div>
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map((user) => <li key={user.id}><Review user={user} /></li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening now. I modified the code based on their comments, but the screen is not re-rendered after the data is fetched using axios. That should solve my problem. Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: @ryo.m.code i glad to help you :) if it works for you please mark my answer as correct answer